# Python Text File To List

Tags: python, list, text, split

I am trying to create a script that will look at a text file and store every word as a separate element in a list.

When trying to use .split() it doesn't seem to split the string into individual elements.

```
RanTxtString = open("randomText.txt", "r")
for word in RanTxtString:
  word.split()
  print(word)
```

Output:

```
c:\Scripts>python TxtToList.py
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Word1 consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc
>   fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.
>
> Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Praesent
>   Word3 sed rhoncus eo. Duis id commodo orci.
>
> Quisque at dignissim lacus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
all_words = word.split()
print(all_words)
```

`split` returns a `list`, it does not change the original `string`.

Update (to get all words in a single list):

```
RanTxtString = open("randomText.txt", "r")
all_words=[]
for word in RanTxtString:
    all_words = all_words+word.split()
print(all_words)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is now breaking down each line into individual strings. However it stores each line separately.

c:\Scripts>python TxtToList.py
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 'Word1', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit.', 'Nunc', 'fringilla', 'arcu', 'congue', 'metus', 'aliquam', 'mollis.']
['Mauris', 'nec', 'maximus', 'purus.', 'Maecenas', 'sit', 'amet', 'pretium', 'tellus.', 'Praesent', 'Word3', 'sed', 'rhoncus', 'eo.', 'Duis', 'id', 'commodo', 'orci.']
['Quisque', 'at', 'dignissim', 'lacus.']

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am trying to store each one in a single list.

Comment: That means words of every different line will be stored in different list?Or a single list will contain all the words?

Comment: Yes single list will contain all the words, thank you for this, greatly appreciated.